# How can I reference a folder inside a Wordpress theme via a relative url and without PHP functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had a static website which was transitioned to a Wordpress one. Since the website was static, its HTML content lives inside the themes `index.php`. The CSS was moved in the `styles.css` folder and the rest of the assets was moved to a folder just inside the theme folder: `./my-custom-theme/assets`.

The problem is that if I reference an asset from the `styles.css`, for example if I have

```
.my-class { 
    background-image: url(assets/images/image1.png)
}
```

then everything works fine, the url gets translated into `website/wordpress/my-custom-theme/assets/image1.png`. However for javascript files rendered as blocks in the main HTML I have to use:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

Is there no way of making Wordpress, the Wordpress theme or even the server serve the static js by using a link relative to the template folder and not using `get_template_directory_uri()` or other helper functions at all?

Comment: You should be able to just use `<script src="assets/js/myjs.js"></script>`

Comment: What does <script src="/wp-content/my-custom-theme/assets/js/myjs.js"></script> do - or similar relative path - I am not 100% sure how you have set your site up

Comment: @LuisÁvila could be, but it certainly does not work, it points to "website/assets/js.." whereas the assets are in the template folder, so not directly in the root folder.

Comment: @SimonPollard I am transitioning from a static html site to a wordpress, however I want to keep the development in the static part, since the whole website is static and I have my whole build scripts and file processing things there. Originally I had relative srcs, like LuisAvila pointed out, however when I move everything inside a theme and that theme in a wordpress folder, the relative path will be relative to web root

Comment: Where are you calling the script from? (You can use ../ to jump one folder back)

Comment: @LuisÁvila I am calling it from "index.php", whose contents have been replaced by static html content, minus those <?php ?> for targeting the theme folder.

Comment: `using a link relative to the template folder`...it will be relative to the generated url of the page so you can define the `/` using a meta tag but this will probably cause errors with other resources so basically no. You could do a rewrite rule in your htaccess but to not cause errors you would have to target ea js file so prob easier to to use php in the end

Answer (score 2):

It is unique case and you may instead use the static URL to reference the files in your theme folder directly instead of using the PHP path, if this theme will be used on some other domain, that URLs will need to be updated again but in your case as it is specific site, with specific theme and need. You may opt for what is not recommended that is putting in place static URLs i.e.
replacing this part get_template_directory_uri() with http://your-domain.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme-folder

then you can have urls like this:

```
<script src="http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/assets/js/myjs.js"></script>
```

Above approach is recommended only when you have to reference WordPress theme assets from some non-PHP page where you cannot use WordPress built-in function for echoing the paths, which is exact case OP is facing.

Comment: Yeah.. I wanted to keep this as independent and self contained as possible (meaning also independent from 'mydomain', etc.), but it seems there's actually no quick fix. ended up leaving the '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>' in. Thanks for the answer!